# Unable to view badges on Oreo 8.1 (27)

Tags: android

I want my application to show badges dot during notification if they are turned on from setting irrespective of any launcher especially "Google Now Launcher " because i cant ask the user to change the launcher to display the dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. Notification badges are a launcher-dependent feature, as it's entirely up to the launcher to decide how app icons should be displayed.

Unless the user has a launcher that supports notification badges (and they have them enabled), they're not going to see them.

Comment: Any alternate solution as Client is asking for it.

Comment: Paytm, Whatsapp & other applications are showing it

Comment: You can't force notification dots, plain and simple. If other applications are showing it while yours isn't then you have a problem in your code.

Comment: I have a similar issue with samsung galaxy S7 device

Comment: As far as I know, the TouchWiz launcher doesn't support notification badges. The S7 is also on 8.0, and not in all regions.

Comment: Earlier i was able to get the badges but after updating the O.S i was unable to get badges.